# Monitor JRockit JVM via SNMP

Tags: java, snmp, jrockit

I would like to monitor my Java application (running in JRockit) via SNMP protocol. I only need some basic informations. Is there any startup parameter that I can add to my app to enable SNMP?

Answer (score 3):

SNMP in JRockit works the same way as in Sun's JVM. The details are on [this webpage](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/SNMP.html).

In short, what you have to do is:

1. Start with `-Dcom.sun.management.snmp.port=portNum`
2. Copy the ACL template file in `JRE_HOME/lib/management/snmp.acl.template` to `JRE_HOME/lib/management/snmp.acl`, and make it readable and writeable by only the owner.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe JRockit can publish stats on SNMP.  What I have seen monitoring systems do is hook-up the the JMX monitoring points within JRockit...

Of course you can also use the JRMC tool which is plugged into the JMX beans mentioned above.

HTH
Tom

Answer (score 0):

The standard JRockit JVM does not support SNMP. The most common approach is to attach a JMX SNMP Connector. I have previously used the [AdventNet one](http://www.adventnet.com/products/snmpadaptor/index.html).